# Comparing blank cells with conditional formating

Tags: excel, formula

I want to highlight Cell F4 if F4 is blank and E4 is not.
So in the scenario below I want the actual visit column to highlight if it is blank AND the 7 day due date is NOT blank.  I am trying to have a visual alert of missed visits.

```
Entry Date               7 Day Due Date Actual Visit Date
12/18/18                 12/24/18              
12/01/18                 12/07/18       12/7/18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please select ColumnF and try a CF formula rule of:

```
=AND(F1="",E1<>"")
```

with formatting of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The condition format based on a formula:

[image]

applied to `$C$2:$C$11`

[image]

highlights a cell based on your condition.

[image]